# Undeletable logging or file-writing

Tags: logging, storage

I want to log or write files automatically to a un-deletable storage device.

Even if the attacker had offline access to the storage device he/she shouldn't be able to delete the files or logs.

If the data is destroyed or changed I should be able to know.

I'm thinking of physical devices like EEPROM.

Comment: If the attacker has access to it why wont he take it or smash it?

Comment: @BubbleHacker I want it to be obvious that the data has been altered or destroyed. The case is detecting inside job.

Comment: The usual method of protecting log data is to send it to a remote syslog server that sits in a secure physical location. Not sure if this would work in your situation but it might be a possible alternative.

Comment: you can use `chattr` to make a file append-only and owned by root to prevent deletion.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional term for this sort of device is **[WORM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many)**, where WORM stands for "**Write Once, Read Many**."  A number of tape-like devices are [still available and in use today](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=shop&q=worm%20disk).  More modern equivalents are DVD-R, CD-R, and specially protected Flash drives.  There are also vendors who have created magnetic (e.g., traditional disk drive) technologies which are write-only, such as [GreenTec's WORMdisk](https://greentec-usa.com/?page_id=244).

EEPROM is unlikely to work for you because of the [relatively small size and slow speeds](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14905/high-capacity-eeprom-chip).

Answer (score 1):

Use a DVD or CD.

First use a marker to write something Unique on the DVD disc. Handwrtiting is the security step here.

Then you could use a CLI tool to automatically burn to the disc.

One could also use Multi-session disc burning.